# How to increase or decrease the spatial resolution of a band in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, sentinel-1

In LANDSAT

```
var mndwi = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA/LC08_148044_20130425").normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('MNDWI')
```

gives us MNDWI Band

In Sentinel 2 the resolutions of Green Band (**B3** is 10m) and SWIR Band (**B11** is 20m) are different. 
How to change SWIR Band to be finer resolution so that I can apply normalized difference?

Comment: you don't need to, see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale

Comment: Thanks. So, Can I directly apply the normalized difference between Green and SWIR Bands? What would be the resolution of the resulting MNDWI Band?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can directly apply the normalized difference between Green and SWIR without any issues. You can even apply any kinds of calculation between Green band of Sentinel and SWIR band of Landsat or whatever data source if you would like to.

In Google Earth Engine, the resolution of the resulting MNDWI (or Landsat/Sentinel/MODIS image) is dynamic, i.e. undetermined until you ask GEE to do something that requires a determined resolution.

For example, when you add the resulting MNDWI image to `Map` (using `Map.addLayer(mndwi)`), GEE will determine the resolution of this image on the fly based on your current zoom level. If you want to fix a single resolution, says 10m, for your image, simply add `mndwi = mndwi.reproject(mndwi.projection(), null, 10)` before adding your image to `Map`.

When exporting an image, GEE requires you to specify a resolution for your image, usually via the `scale` argument. Yes you can pick any value for the resolution.

More on image resolution in GEE from [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale#scale-of-analysis).